# echo command behaviour issue in bash

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

```
command="echo 'hello world' > file.txt";
$command;
```

And I'm expecting that it will write the "hello world" text to file.txt,
But it prints the whole string as,

```
'hello world' > file.txt
```

What wrongs with my code?

Comment: There are no sensible reasons to put the command in a variable in your case. Just use a function: `mycommand() { echo 'hello world' > file.txt; }` and then call it when you want it to be executed: `mycommand`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a variable is replaced, the result is only scanned for word splitting and wildcard expansion. Other special shell characters, such as quotes and redirection, are not processed. You need to use `eval` to reprocess it completely:

```
eval "$command"
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store full command line in variables and execute like this.

Using this will work but **is dangerous** if command line is coming from users or from an external source:

```
bash -c "$command"
```

**Safe approach** is to store command in BASH array:

```
command=(echo 'hello world')
```

And execute it like this:

```
"${command[@]}" > file.txt
```

Comment: He wants the redirection in the variable, you're hard-coding it in the script.

Comment: I have given both solutions but won't prefer keeping `> file.txt` in the variable.